# UITableViewCell clipsToBound not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

In my custom cell I have written `[self setClipsToBound : YES]` and then adding these red imageViews as its subviews as `[self addSubview:imageView]`

But as you can see the imageView is not getting clipped.

I searched, but din't find any success!

Comment: Can you post code on which layer have your created the rounded corners?

Comment: Are you using a grouped tableView?

Comment: I am using UITableViewStyleGrouped @MarkM Yes!

Comment: Check my answer. In order to add an image to the background of a grouped cell you need to add it as a background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is your grouped tableView, is very unintuitive the fact that a grouped table view cell has the same width as a normal table view, the only difference is that a grouped table view has a different cell background (also for selected state) and margins for the content of the cell which are created by a different position of the cells labels.

You should create assets with top right and bottom right corners rounded (for first cell and last cell from a section). The clipSubview won't work for your case because the imageView dosen't rich out of the cells content.

Comment: Or you could use grouped cells and have them auto create the top, middle and bottom rounded corner cells for you and use the solution I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to add an image to the background of a grouped cell.

```
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, yourCell.frame.size.width, 80)]; // Modify this for your cell
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imgView.image];
```

Comment: Explanation: clipsToBounds is a method on UIView and concerns a rectangular area. Rounded corners is dealt with at the underlying CALayer level and is a "mask". It's possible to set an appropriate mask on a rounded corner layer to achieve the desired clipping, the background property will do this by default (especially in a situation where the corner rounding code is hidden from you).